# In a leftist heap tree, is the distance varibale calculated by going to null the fastest in ANY way possible?

Tags: data-structures, heap

So I'm studying leftist heap tree when I came across this property that intrigued  me

**Heavier on left side : dist(right(i)) <= dist(left(i)). Here, dist(i) is the number of edges on the shortest path from node i to a leaf node in extended binary tree representation (In this representation, a null child is considered as external or leaf node). The shortest path to a descendant external node is through the right child. Every subtree is also a leftist tree and dist( i ) = 1 + dist( right( i ) ).**

Now according to that property, the distance varible is calculated by calculating the fastest route to a null  . So let's say if I have a tree which looks something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZbsY.jpg)

So I've read the leftist tree properties for more than an hour  now and it only states that it follows min heap and dist left > dist right. So according to it that tree should be legal (forgive me if I missed something). I've drawn on the tree two  possible paths for that node to get to null, one way is going backwards through root, one way is keep processing downward. Now the question that I'm asking is this : Which one should I take, since there's no limitation that says I can't take the 1, I should take it because it's better ? Or when inserting elements into the heap, do we do it in someway that this never happens ? Again I'm sorry if I missed something because I'm new, but I've spent a while trying to figure this out, and even if the latter is true, why do we want it to be .

Answer (score 0):

The distance of a node *v* is calculated as *d(v) = -1* if *v* is null, otherwise *d(v) = 1 + min(d(c_l), d(c_r))* where *c_l* and *c_r* are the left and right children of *v*. Leftist heap *H* is binary heap with the property that *d(c_l) >= d(c_r)* for each *v* in *H*.

Thus, in your case you should take the right path and claim that the distance of the node *1* is 0.

(The purpose of the leftist heap is to enable fast union of two heaps. When the merge operation is defined, the insert operation is implemented by using the merge.)